# Why this simple jQuery code does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why this simple jQuery code won't load in my browser. It's simple code that should display corner box that can be closed. I think the code is ok but it seems like the jQuery isn't loaded properly. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .kutija{
            display: none;
            border: 2px solid red;
            height: 200px;
            width = 200px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .close{
            background-color: coral;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".close").click(function(){
            $(".kutija").fadeOut;
        });   
        $(".kutija").delay(2000).slideDown(1000);
     });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="kutija">
       <div class="close">
           X
        </div>
        <div>
            Da li vam je potrebna pomoc?
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".kutija").fadeOut();` Call your function first

Comment: You cannot have a `<script src="...">` which also has content. A script must *either* have a `src` attribute, *or* code to be run inside it.

Answer (score 3):

`fadeOut` is a method

```
 $(".kutija").fadeOut();
```

Also keep a separate script tag for content and separate for downloading jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".close").click(function(){
            $(".kutija").fadeOut();
        });   
        $(".kutija").delay(2000).slideDown(1000);
     });
</script>
```

As per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT)

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via the URI.

Comment: That's only one of the two problems ;)

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yeah I was wrong. Edited the code alignment in question just now

Comment: Thanks a lot. The separate script tag resolve my problem. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The way that you used the script tags is [prohibited in HTML 5](http://w3c.github.io/html/#the-script-element).

And as per the [HTML4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) the `If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI`.

That's the reason your script is being "ignored".

Also `fadeOut()` is a method, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Please write JQuery code in separate < script language="javascript" >... below < script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">

and change $(".kutija").fadeOut; ===> $(".kutija").fadeOut();